# How do I add a widget to my lock screen?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screen-widgets, nova-launcher

I am running a fully stock Android 4.4.4 Nexus 5, with Nova (Premium) Launcher. Since I first bought this device, I have heard, read, and been told that adding widgets to the lock screen is possible, as long as it is enabled in settings. Well, it is, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to actually add them.

Sorry if this is a Super Newb question, I've Googled, Binged, etc...  With no luck whatsoever. The only thing I seem to ever come across are instructions on how to enable them, which as I stated, I have done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the lock screen widgets from `Settings > Security > Check "Enable Widgets"`. Once done, go to lock screen, swipe from towards right hand and now you will be able add widgets there.

Comment: Right, like I said, it is enabled in my settings. When I swipe from right to left on my lock screen, the camera is activated. (Just out of curiosity and frustration, I tried swiping from left to right, and NOTHING happens.)

Comment: Yeah, once enabled, you have to swipe towards right i.e. from left to right. Not sure why are't you getting the screen to add widgets.